# PHP 5.3.1 not loading php_oci8.dll on Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, php

I'm trying to load the oracle extension on php but im having the error:

> **Warning**:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\Program Files\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
>    in **Unknown** on line **0**

I have done so far:

1. Included on  windows path the the fullpath of oracle instant client
2. on php.ini, the `extension_dir` is pointing to the right place
3. on php.ini `extension=php_oci8.dll` is ok
4. restarted the apache, and nothing works.

Comment: Did you tried to set `extention_dir` absolutly? Did you tried to empty `extention_dir` and set `extention=php.oci8.dll` absolutly? Are you sure `php_oci8.dll` is for your machine (32/64bit?)

Comment: I belive extension dir is working , because i can successfully connect to a mysql and postgresql database. The php_oci8.dll im using was installed with xampp. The pc im using is 32 bits, so the dll.

Comment: PHP 5.3.1? Why are you using such an out-of-date version? The current version is 5.3.17. There have been a **lot** of patches in between those versions, including a lot of security patches.

Comment: Because i just it for personal book/dvd's database. No need to upgrade anything :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved by copying the files orannzsbb11.dll , oci.dll and oraociei11.dll to c:\windows\system32

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext" to my Windows PATH environment variable. You'll just have to remember to change the path if you upgrade PHP. I think this is better than copying dlls which could lead to issues down the road if you end up with multiple dlls with different versions on the same machine.

Comment: We discussed that problem, but we decided it was better to add the dll's into the system32 folder.

Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download Oracle Instant client from this hyperlink http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html  .
Add the path to the instant client on the user environment vriables and the system variables.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was caused by not having the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (for VC9) installed. I had to get the x64 package as I'm running Windows 7 64bit. Hopefully this helps someone with the same problem. After installing it, PHP no longer reported those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly quite obvious to some, but wasn't initially for me: if you're still seeing this `The specified procedure could not be found. in Unknown on line 0` error, even after installing the instant client, SDK, and so on - make sure you put the Oracle instant client path in your **system** "PATH" variable, not the **user** variable, as user obviously doesn't get used when Apache runs. You can verify that the instant client path is set properly by reviewing the PATH value shown in your phpinfo() output.

Answer (score 0):

I found the main cause behind this issue is the oci8 driver version of oracle. Finally i was able to connect to oracle and the steps i described here at http://angularcode.com/connecting-php-to-oracle-database-10g/

Comment: The link to your article returns a 404 page not found error.