# Xampp configuration PHP error

Tags: php, configuration, xampp

I have a question regarding Xampp php oci8 configuration. I installed Oracle instant client 32 Bit version and downloaded the correspoding dlls from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.8/windows) in the 32 Bit version. I added them to xampp_installation/php/ext and replaced the old files.

I added all installation pathes to the PATH.

When I now want to start apache I get:

> The programm is not able to start, because OCI.dll is missing on the
>   machine. Please install the programm again, to solve the problem
>   (translated from German).

And then:

Warning:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library C:...\php_oci8.dll is
>   missing

Has anybody an idea what is wrong there. It is blocking me for 2 days now.

Thanks in advance,

Sebastian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 5.3.1 not loading php\_oci8.dll on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820429/php-5-3-1-not-loading-php-oci8-dll-on-windows)

Comment: Please Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825405/php-warning-at-startup-while-trying-to-load-php-oci8-dll

Comment: It is still not working I followed the instructions on the google page.